# More usage of getTransformToElement

Tags: svg

I could not find much details on getTransformToElement method, and how to use it correctly.

From the spec

> "Returns the transformation matrix
>   from the user coordinate system on the
>   current element (after application of
>   the ‘transform’ attribute, if any) to
>   the user coordinate system on
>   parameter element (after application
>   of its ‘transform’ attribute, if
>   any)."

Terminology like, SVG canvas, viewbox, viewport, user cordinate, screen cordinate (http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/coords.html) etc make it hard to understand what exactly this interface is used for.

thanks,

bsr

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It returns a [Transformation Matrix](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/coords.html#TransformMatrixDefined), I wouldn't worry too much about that other terminology for now.  If you have some SVG like this:

```
<svg id="mysvg" viewBox="0 0 640 480">
    <g transform="skewX(45) skewY(33)">
        <text x="60" y="290" id="mytext">Example</text>
    </g>
</svg>
```

You can then use `getTransformToElement` like this:

```
//Get the SVG root for context
var s = document.getElementById('mysvg');
//Get a reference to the element
var t = document.getElementById('mytext');
//Find the transformation that would need to be applied to s to put it in the same co-ordinate space as t
var m = s.getTransformToElement(t);
```

At the end of that code m will be an object representing a matrix (there's a bunch of methods too, but I'm ignoring them):

```
m = {a: 1, b: -0.6494075655937195, c: -1, d: 1.6494076251983643, e: 0, f: 0}
```

You can then use that matrix to apply the same transform as on `mytext` relative to `mysvg` to any other element as per the matrix multiplication from the SVG spec:

[image: image of matrix multiplication]

As noted in the comment below this method is deprecated in favour of [`getCTM` in the upcoming SVG 2 standard](https://svgwg.org/svg2-draft/types.html#__svg__SVGGraphicsElement__getCTM).

Comment: getTransformToElement has been deprecated as of Feb,2016: https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-svg/2015Aug/att-0009/SVGWG-F2F-minutes-20150824.html#item02

Answer (score 10):

possible replacement for

```
fromElement.getTransformToElement(toElement)
```

is

```
toElememnt.getScreenCTM().inverse().multiply( fromElement.getScreenCTM() )
```