# How to get getBBox of a path after applying transform

Tags: javascript, svg, drawing, snap.svg, translate-animation

I have this `svg` block ,this group can drag so the transform matrix changes everytime while i drag

```
<g id="product_1240" transform="matrix(-0.5032,0.8642,-0.8642,-0.5032,80.0928,78.4287)" class="elements">
<path id="p1" d="m -25, -15 l 50,0 l 0,30 l -50,0 z" fill="#fc7f4c" stroke="#FC7F4C" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke" style="opacity: 0.3;" class="elements" opacity="0.3"></path>
<path id="p2" d="m -20, -10 l 40,0 l 0,20 l -40,0 z" fill="#e5e5e5" stroke="#cccccc" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"></path>
</g>
```

i can get the `getBBox()` of the element `product_1240` like this

```
console.log($('#product_1240')[0].getBBox());
```

this is working fine ,but if i do

```
console.log($('#p1')[0].getBBox());
```

im getting result but its static through out the drag because there is no transform to `p1` but only to its parent `g`.My question is is there anyway to get the `getBBox()` of element `p1` after applying the transform matrix of its parent `g`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getTransformToElement()` may be what you are after.

[More usage of getTransformToElement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5891552/more-usage-of-gettransformtoelement)

Once you have the transform, you can apply it to each of the bbox points to get your transformed bbox.

Comment: Deprecated according to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5891552/more-usage-of-gettransformtoelement#comment68046581_6084322