# Get the current matrix transformation of an SVG element

Tags: javascript, svg, matrix, transformation

I know a very easy way to get the current matrix transformation of any SVG element:

```
// 't' is a string
var t = window.getComputedStyle(nativeElement, null).transform
console.log(t);
```

The problem is that the previous method returns numbers with no more than six decimals. For example, the previous code may return:

```
matrix(0.965926, 0.258819, -0.258819, 0.965926, 0, 0)
```

Is there a way to get the matrix transformation of any SVG element more accurately?

Comment: is the transform an attribute or a style?

Comment: transform is an attribute: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/transform

Comment: you're treating it as a style in the question, that's why I asked. If it's a style there's not much to be done, if it's an attribute you can get it via the DOM.

Comment: This *is* an accurate 2D transformation matrix - there are only six numbers (a-f) in a 2D affine matrix. What do you mean by more accurately?

Comment: The "transform" attribute returns six floating number with a limited precision (6 decimal digits). By "accurately" I mean returning more decimal digits. The question has been solved in the next answer.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To get the current `transform` attribute as an `SVGMatrix` object, you can use:

```
element.transform.baseVal.consolidate().matrix
```

```js
var myrect = document.getElementById("myrect");

console.log(myrect.transform.baseVal.consolidate().matrix);
```

```html
<svg>
  <rect id="myrect" width="10" height="10" transform="scale(2) rotate(45)"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: What do you think about the solution in my answer below? Is it the same matrix object, or do you know some difference to your solution?

Comment: As Robert said below, your solution is different.  It only gives the same result as long as no ancestor elements have a transform.  That includes other attributes that cause transformations also, such as a `viewBox`.

Answer (score 2):

Consolidation can change your element 'transform' attribute value.
You can also get a matrix without changing the transformation attribute by transforming the element matrix to the parent.

See documentation about the:

```
getTransformToElement
```

```js
function getMatrix(element) {
  var matrix = element.parentNode
     .getScreenCTM()
     .inverse()
     .multiply(element.getScreenCTM());
  return matrix;
}
var myrect = document.getElementById("myrect");

console.log(getMatrix(myrect));
```

```html
<svg>
  <rect id="myrect" width="10" height="10" transform="scale(2) rotate(45)"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: See this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5891552/more-usage-of-gettransformtoelement

Also, you may want to have the reference element as a parameter of the function instead of being hard coded to `element.parentNode`, like this: `const getMatrix = (to, from) =>
  to.getScreenCTM().inverse().multiply(from.getScreenCTM());`.

Answer (score 2):

In the case if you know that your SVG element has no ancestors wich were transformed you can use [`SVGelement.getCTM()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/types.html#__svg__SVGLocatable__getCTM) function for it because it is shorter. I think that CTM in the function name is the short form from «current transformation matrix».

```js
var rect = document.querySelector("#rect");

console.log(rect.getCTM());
```

```html
<svg>
    <rect id="rect" width="10" height="10" transform="scale(2) rotate(45)"/>
</svg>
```

**Difference `rect.getCTM()` vs. `rect.transform.baseVal.consolidate().matrix`**

But you should be careful about the use from this function because it only gives the same result like from the matrix `rect.transform.baseVal.consolidate().matrix`as long as no ancestor elements have a transform. For example:

```js
var rect = document.querySelector("#rect"),
    ctmMatrix = rect.getCTM(),
    baseValMatrix = rect.transform.baseVal.consolidate().matrix;

console.log('CTM Matrix: translateX = '+ctmMatrix.e+', translateY = '+ctmMatrix.f);
console.log('BaseVal Matrix: translateX = '+baseValMatrix.e+', translateY = '+baseValMatrix.f);
```

```html
<svg>
    <g transform="translate(35,45)">
        <rect id="rect" width="10" height="10" transform="translate(35,45)"/>
    </g>
</svg>
```

I thank @PaulLeBeau for the explanation about the difference between this matrixes.

Comment: This is the transform of the element and its ancestors.