# Get transformation from node in d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Is it possible to obtain the current transformation (translate in particular, i.e. set by `.attr('transform', 'translate(20, 10)')`) from an svg group element using d3 in `transform` form (from d3-transform)? I manage to get the attribute (`select('g').attr('transform')`), but need to convert this somehow into a `transform` object/function to chain more transformations and reapply it to the node.

I try to translate the `g` element as part of the dragging. It does not contain an `x`/`y` attribute (as with many other drag examples). Instead, it specifies those `transform()` attributes for correct placement.

My current approach is `$g.node().transform.baseVal[0].matrix.e` to get the x-value of the transformation, but I was hoping for a more "d3-integrated" approach.

Comment: Borderline XY-problem... To get a decent D3 answer please post your code and describe what exactly you are trying to achieve, i.e. the expected behavior.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can do it by requesting transformation matrix of the  element:

```
const matrix = select('g').node().transform.baseVal.consolidate().matrix
const translateX = matrix.e
const translateY = matrix.f
const scale = matrix.d
```

Here is a [more detailed explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46434687/get-the-current-matrix-transformation-of-an-svg-element).