# Find SVG Circle segment position to hover a tooltip

Tags: javascript, html, svg, tooltip, positioning

Suppose I have an SVG doughnut chart. I would like to have a tooltip on hover on each segment. See the snippet below.
For example:

- first segment find the middle relative position on the screen and have a tooltip appear on the right bottom corner.
- second segment find the middle relative position on the screen and have a tooltip appear on the left top corner.

I've tried [This approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53118805/5171353) but was only able to get the position of the chart itself but not the segment.

```
private getCirclePosition(elem: { target: SVGCircleElement; }) {
 let svg = elem.target.ownerSVGElement;
 let pt = svg.createSVGPoint();

 pt.x = elem.target.cx.baseVal.value;
 pt.y = elem.target.cy.baseVal.value;

 return pt.matrixTransform(this.getTransformToElement(elem, svg));
}

private getTransformToElement(fromElement: { target: SVGCircleElement; }, toElement: SVGSVGElement) {
 return toElement.getCTM().inverse().multiply(fromElement.target.getCTM());
}
```

I am not using `chart.js` or `d3.js` but trying to accomplish this in js and HTML. Please suggest me with any point of direction where I am not doing it correctly.

```html
<svg width="250px" height="250px" viewBox="0 0 42 42" class="donut">
  <circle class="donut-hole" cx="21" cy="21" r="15.91549430918954" fill="#fff"></circle>
  <circle class="donut-ring" cx="21" cy="21" r="15.91549430918954" 
    fill="transparent" stroke="#DCDCDE" stroke-width="4"></circle>
   <circle class="donut-segment" cx="21" cy="21" r="15.91549430918954" 
    fill="transparent" stroke="#5C6BC0" stroke-dasharray="70 30" stroke-dashoffset="25" stroke-width="4"></circle>
   <circle class="donut-segment" cx="21" cy="21" r="15.91549430918954"
    fill="transparent" stroke="#66BB6A" stroke-dasharray="25 75" stroke-dashoffset="55" stroke-width="4"></circle>
  </svg>
```

Comment: You need to calculate center points of each segment?