# svg getCTM() not returning expected x/y values

Tags: javascript, svg

I am working with a SVG element as following.

The pattern of this SVG is that the SVG element `circle in this case` would always have some parent element `<g><g></g></g> in this case` and the parent element may or may not have some sort of `transform` attributes and the element itself may or may not have some sort of `transform` attributes.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js"></script>

<body>
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1280 720">
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="1280" height="720" fill="ghostwhite"></rect>
        <g transform="translate(10,10)">
            <g transform="translate(100 100)">
                <circle id="circ" r="20" cx="25" cy="25" fill="green"
                transform="translate (100,400) scale(2)" />
            </g>
        </g>
    </svg>
</body>
</html>
```

I need to know the absolute `x,y(transformMatrix.e, transformMatrix.f)` coordinate of the `circle` element that equates to the cumulative transform of each of the attributes coming from any of its parent elements plus its own transform element.

So, in this case, I want javascript to return `x=10+100+25*2+100=260` and `y=10+100+25*2+400=560`.

I tried using [getCTM()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGGraphicsElement) as my understanding was it takes into account the effect of all cumulative transform for a particular element and tried it like this. I also took [help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53118805/11156131) from this post to convert `DOMMatrix` to `svgMatrix`.

However, it does not quite do the job. The javascript returns `convertedMatrix.e=210 and convertedMatrix.f=510`. I don't know where this is going wrong in using **`getCTM()`**.

I can't figure out how can I achieve the desired using this approach and what adjustments do I need to make here?

```js
const toElement = document.querySelector('svg');
const fromElement = document.querySelector('circle')
const toCTM = toElement.getCTM();
const fromCTM = fromElement.getCTM();
const convertedMatrix = toCTM.inverse().multiply(fromCTM);
console.log(convertedMatrix);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js"></script>

<body>
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1280 720">
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="1280" height="720" fill="ghostwhite"></rect>
        <g transform="translate(10,10)">
            <g transform="translate(100 100)">
                <circle id="circ" r="20" cx="25" cy="25" fill="green"
                transform="translate (100,400) scale(2)" />
            </g>
        </g>
    </svg>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
</script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The transform matrix is not the same as the result of its application to a point. The transform list

```
translate(10,10) translate(100 100) translate(100,400) scale(2)
```

consolidates to (note the `a` and `d` values)

```
matrix(2, 0, 0, 2, 210, 510)
```

and make this computation:

```
cx' = cx * 2 + 210
cy' = cy * 2 + 510
```

For a point `(25, 25)`, this computes to

```
25 * 2 + 210 = 260
25 * 2 + 510 = 510
```

just like you expected.

In the form of a script, you need to construct a point that the matrix can be applied to. Then read its coordinates. Don't bother about the old interfaces SVGMatrix and SVGPoint, that is a problem of ten years past.

What you *need* to bother about is the result of implicit transformations by the `viewBox` and `preserveAspectRatio` attributes. They are included in the matrix produced by `.getCTM()`.

If you want to *exclude* the [implicit transformation](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG2/coords.html#ComputingAViewportsTransform), you need to apply it inversely, which is what the code you took from the linked answer does.

*Note: I am a bit stumped to find that Firefox returns `null` on `svg.getCTM()`. That is a bug. Chrome handles that case correctly.*

```js
const svg = document.querySelector('svg');
const matrixViewBox = svg.getCTM();
const circle = document.querySelector('circle');
const matrixCircle = circle.getCTM();
const x = circle.cx.baseVal.value; // takes care of unit conversion
const y = circle.cy.baseVal.value;

console.log(new DOMPoint(x, y).matrixTransform(matrixCircle));

matrixFromCircleToViewBox = matrixViewBox.inverse().multiply(matrixCircle);
console.log(new DOMPoint(x, y).matrixTransform(matrixFromCircleToViewBox));
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="640" height="360" viewBox="0 0 1280 720">
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="1280" height="720" fill="ghostwhite"></rect>
    <g transform="translate(10,10)">
        <g transform="translate(100 100)">
            <circle id="circ" r="20" cx="25" cy="25" fill="green"
            transform="translate (100,400) scale(2)" />
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Many thanks for this. I tested out your answer on a few svg elements. If my elements have a  x/y attribute, it is easier to get tot the following `const x = circle.cx.baseVal.value;` or to `const y = circle.cy.baseVal.value;`. However, if I have a `path` element which does not have x/y attribute, how do I come to to const x/y in that case. For example, if I markup contains this, `<g transform="translate(10,10)"><g transform="translate(100 100)"><path d="M0,0 L150,0 L150,50 L0,50 Z" fill="none", stroke="red" transform="translate (100,400) scale(2)" /></g></g>`, how do I apply the calculation

Comment: You'll have to parse the path string. Unfortunately, the attempt to establish an interface [SVGPathSeg](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/paths.html#InterfaceSVGPathSeg) has failed and it was removed from the SVG 2 spec. There are multiple parser libraries at [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=svg+path+parser), and for the application of transforms to path data, I have written a [library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pathfit) myself. That said, do you really need to know the coordinates of every control point, or would for example the bounding box be enough?

Comment: If I have a path element, I simply need to know the final x and y of that path that gets consolidated from each of its parent elements and the path itself.

Comment: Also, while we are still on this, can you please shed some light on what kind of adjustments do I need to make, should the svg contains `viewbox` and / `preserveAspectRatio`.

Comment: I've edited the answer to handle that case. My apologies for not carefully investigating what that `.inverse()` in your code was really about.

Comment: Just checking should `const svg = document.querySelector('circle');` be `const svg = document.querySelector('svg');?` The first line of your code.

Comment: Yes, corrected.

Comment: Many thanks for this. It correctly solves my problem, as long as the element has `x`,`y` attributes. Path will probably be a different approach.

Comment: was wondering whether `const svg = document.querySelector('svg');const matrixViewBox = svg.getCTM();const path = document.querySelector('path');const len = path.getTotalLength();const pct = 0;const pathPoint = path.getPointAtLength(len * pct);const matrixPath = path.getCTM();const x1 = pathPoint.x;const y1 = pathPoint.y;const matrixFromPathToViewBox = matrixViewBox.inverse().multiply(matrixPath);console.log(new DOMPoint(x1, y1).matrixTransform(matrixFromPathToViewBox));` be correct approach to take for path?

Comment: `.getPointAtLength()` already returns a `DOMPoint`, so there is no need to construct it. Otherwise, it looks doable.

Comment: `getScreenCTM` instead of `getCTM` works in both Mozilla and Chrome.